# Simple bash get part of a string

Tags: linux, bash

I have this text and more stored in a `$hello`:

```
"id":"1234"
```

How can I find id, and then get just the number?

There will be a lot of other text in the string.

Whole string is:
After making says:

```
{"self":"http://xxxxx:8081/rest/api/latest/version/1234","id":"1234","description":"desc","name":"vi1teast","archived":false,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2016-02-06","overdue":true,"userReleaseDate":"06/Feb/16","projectId":xxxxx}
```

I cannot use any JSON parsers, must be with string manipulation!

Comment: what is whole string??what you have tried so far??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse a JSON, use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)!

```
$ jq '.id' file
"1234"
```

And if you don't want to get the quotes, use [`-r`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq):

```
$ jq -r '.id' file
1234
```

From the manual:

> `--raw-output / -r`:
>
> With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be
>   written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a
>   JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk
>   to non-JSON-based systems.

Note I had to tweak your JSON and write `"projectId":"xxxxx"` so that it is a valid one.

Comment: It seems the OP doesn't want to use a parser.

Comment: @Kenavoz life is crazy. Now my answer was accepted, so apparently the OP managed to get one parser.

Comment: It seems the OP has come to understand that one should use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @fedorqui This is the right way. +1 for your educational approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the id and can make sure that it will only contain digits, you can use a pure bash solution like this. It will use bash regex and `BASH_REMATCH` for referencing the capturing groups.

```
#!/bin/bash
str='{"self":"http://xxxxx:8081/rest/api/latest/version/1234","id":"1234","description":"desc","name":"vi1teast","archived":false,"released":false,"releaseDate":"2016-02-06","overdue":true,"userReleaseDate":"06/Feb/16","projectId":xxxxx}'
if [[ "$str" =~ ^.*\"id\":\"([0-9]*)\".*$ ]]; 
then 
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ; 
else 
  echo "Not propper format"; 
fi
```

This will output the desired `1234`.

You can also shorten it up:

```
#short version
[[ "$str" =~ ^.*\"id\":\"([0-9]*)\".*$ ]] && id=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo $id
```

Comment: No need for `^.*` and `.*$`: `[[ "$str" =~ \"id\":\"([0-9]*)\" ]]`

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I thought you alway have to match the full line.

Comment: And to avoid all these annoying backslashes: `[[ "$str" =~ '"id":"'([0-9]*)'"' ]]` Only the regex part is left unquoted: `([0-9]*)`

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use a parser, try this sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*"id":"\([0-9]\+\)".*/\1/' <<< "$hello"
1234
```